# How to access database with Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I'm learning how to use ADF to build a webservice based desktop application.
I already have the code that sync webservice data with local derby database(for cache) from exist project.
Is there anyway to access database directly via ORM/entity or something that ADF generated?
Is creating JPA persistence unit xml files & Toplink sessions a correct way coding with ADF applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Not sure I've understood you correctly)

To create database connection:

1. Application Navigator -> Application Resources panel
2. right click on Connections folder -> New connection -> Database...

Then you create Application Module, put Entity Objects there and so on